# How to output wordpress stylesheet uri in typeahead js

Tags: wordpress, typeahead, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am using typeahead with bootstrap 3 and its working fine. my only issue is that i can't output get_stylesheet_directory_uri() in the url that remote my json countries data without hardcoding the whole url manually.
NB : I am using the last typeahead.js version from twitter.
Here is my code :

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
   limit: 10,
   prefetch: {
   url: ' http://Mydomainname.fr/wp-content/themes/inkness-child/lib/data/countries.json',
filter: function(list) {
  return $.map(list, function(country) { return { name: country }; });
    }
  }
});

countries.initialize();

$('.example-countries .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
name: 'countries',
displayKey: 'name',
source: countries.ttAdapter()
});
```

I googled little bit and found this :

```
var templateUrl = '<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>';
```

and i tried to implent it like this but fails

```
url: +templateUrl+/lib/data/countries.json,
```

Please help.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Output the URL with `echo`:

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
```

For example:

```
url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/data/countries.json',
```

See the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

Comment: thank you for your quick help.. I have already tried that but no lack and tried it again as you mentioned. the autocomplete is not working.I made sure to see if what you suggested is echoing the right path and its ok. I tried hardcoding the url path and worked again. In my opinion js does'nt interept the php tags .any idea?